# Testing database state with South

Tags: django, testing, django-south

I've got a Django project, using South for migrations.  I'd like to write a test that can run on commits as they come in to the main repo that the migrations actually work.  I can test that all migrations run into a clean database, but I'd like to also be able to test that the current database state matches what's defined by the models to catch any commits which failed to add a migration or failed to include a merge migration.  Does South provide a way to do this, or is there another way? Comparing the final database state to the generated state of a syncdb --all won't work as there are some funky migrations that cause a syncdb on certain apps to fail.